# Python Pyramid parse json

Tags: python, json, post, pyramid

I'm posting json to a Python Pyramid server, but I can't parse it on the server side.

The post request look like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:6543/linefollower/7/send_result", 
type: "POST",
data: '{"results": [{"robot_name": "Satikas", "result": null, "team_nr": 30, "team_name": "IT Vennad", "id": 57}]}',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json"
}
```

But on the server side I'm receiving this when I do print(request.body)

```
b'%5B%7B%22robot_name%22%3A+%22Satikas%22%2C+%22result%22%3A+null%2C+%22team_nr%22%3A+30%2C+%22team_name%22%3A+%22IT+Vennad%22%2C+%22id%22%3A+57%7D%5D='
```

What should I do to be able to parse the posted content as JSON? When should Pyramid's request.json_body contain the parsed json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly serializing the data as JSON before sending it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:6543/linefollower/7/send_result", 
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({"results": [... "team_name": "IT Vennad", "id": 57}]}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the perfect answer but i can tell you that it's something related to encoding. str.encode() or u'str maybe. You could start looking in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your Data object is a string.  It should just be a object.  Remove the quotes

```
data: {"results": [{"robot_name": "Satikas", "result": null, "team_nr": 30, "team_name": "IT Vennad", "id": 57}]},
```